# Como saber qual o componente que está com o foco?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Estou fazendo um formulário (Windows Forms) em C# e gostaria de saber como faço para pegar o componente que está com o foco. No meu formulário existe um `SplitterPanel` e dentro dele, no `Panel2`, tem um `TabControl` com vários: `ComboBox`, `TextBox` e `Button`. Tentei utilizar a propriedade `ActiveControl`, porém ao invés de pegar o componente com o foco, ela pega o `SplitterPanel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nessa pergunta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/435433/221800) acho que tem a resposta que você deseja. Me corrija se estiver errado. Você tem razão na sua afirmação. Eu destaco as duas primeiras respostas lá.

Método que varre os controles para achar qual está em foco (criei como método de extensão já que ele pode ser bastante útil para todos os controles):

```
public static Control FindFocusedControl(this Control control) {
    var container = control as IContainerControl;
    while (container != null) {
        control = container.ActiveControl;
        container = control as IContainerControl;
    }
    return control;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/WhichInFocus.cs).

Forma de usar:

```
formulario.ActiveControl.FindFocusedControl();
```

Ou tem uma forma usando a API Win32:

```
public class MyForm : Form {
      [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Winapi)]
      internal static extern IntPtr GetFocus();

      private Control GetFocusedControl() {
           Control focusedControl;
           // To get hold of the focused control:
           IntPtr focusedHandle = GetFocus();
           if(focusedHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                // Note that if the focused Control is not a .Net control, then this will return null.
                focusedControl = Control.FromHandle(focusedHandle);
           return focusedControl;
      }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/WhichInFocusWin32.cs).

Comment: eu tinha encontrado um código semelhante ao primeiro exemplo, porém ele percorria **todos** os componentes (não achei isso  legal), mas esse que você passou, percorre somente a hierarquia até chegar ao componente com o foco, pelo que testei `FindFocusedControl` foi mais rápido que `GetFocusedControl` (usei `Stopwatch` para testar). Obs.: a extensão realmente simplifica as coisas, porém ela está com problemas e não está funcionando

Comment: Quais problemas?

Comment: `container` não definido no contexto; `control = container.ActiveControl;` dá erro quando `container` é nulo; falta de `;` no final de linha do `while`... são coisas simples, só que seria bom deixar a resposta correta!

Comment: Veja agora. Foi só falta de atenção na correria.

Comment: os erros ainda continuam, se você colocar o código da sua primeira resposta e só fazer ele como uma extensão, funciona perfeitamente!

Comment: Acho que agora achei o problema. É que não tenho o Visual Studio para testar.

Comment: entendi, o erro ainda continua, o problema ocorrendo nessa linha `control = container.ActiveControl;`, pois na última iteração o `container` é nulo, posso ajustar ou acha melhor você mesmo arrumar?

Comment: Se você consegue, pode arrumar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode testar se o controle retornado pela propriedade ActiveControl é um controle do tipo Container (ou seja implementa a interface IContainerControl).
Se sim, você busca o ActiveControl do container.

Eis um exemplo que fiz no evento MouseUp do formulário:

```
private void Form1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var formSender = (Form)sender;

    var controle = formSender.ActiveControl;

    while (controle is IContainerControl)
    {
        var container = controle as IContainerControl;
        controle = container.ActiveControl;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(controle.Name);
}
```

Att.

Answer (score -1):

Fiz mas está apresentando esta mensagem:
Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class,
na linha onde eu defino a partial class:
public partial class frmReferencias : Form